# Get .NET thread type?

Tags: .net, multithreading

From my current process in .NET I can get a list of all its threads. Is it possible to find out what kind of thread it is? To get details if it's for example a worker, IO, CLR, backgroud or main thread?

Answer (score 0):

There is not going to be a one-size-fits-all solution for doing this.

- You can check the `Thread.IsBackground` property to see if it is a background thread (that is according to the definition of background that the property is using that is).
- You can take advantage of the `Thread.Name` name property to identify it later.
- You can use [thread local storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh(VS.71).aspx) to stuff information "into" a thread which you can extract later to identify it.
- You can use the `Thread.IsThreadPoolThread` to see if it is a thread managed by the thread pool.

Each of these has their own advantages and disadvantages. I think you are going to find it difficult to identify a thread without having attached some kind of information to it ahead of time.